# What software(s) should I install on new system(with Linux as a OS) to prevent it from getting hacked?

Tags: linux, security, email

I am switching to new system with a OS using Linux.I will be using another system which has windows ultimate which is hacked.I am being cyber bullied.
I have given a reference to this as a question on stackexchange.

Now I want to install some softwares on my system with linux that I havnt started it which can prevent from being hacked or being traced in any way.

A fear that I have is

-If I make a new email,it may be traced or hacked easily unless I contact old emails which I will not.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18849/what-do-i-need-to-worry-about-when-moving-from-a-compromised-system-to-a-clean-o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being 'traced' and being 'hacked' are two very different issues but I'll cover them in a broad sense.

If you need to surf anonymously you can use something like TOR to anonymize the traffic but that's not likely necessary.

Unless the person harassing you has recurring access to your old email addresses using them for recovery isn't a problem.  If they do you should change the password and security questions.  If your email host supports phone, text, or PIN security you should enable that.  GMail is an example of an email host that provides this.  If you can still log into your old email address you *can* kick them out of it if you make sure to change everything.

What likely happened to your windows installation wasn't the result of being hacked.  You most likely opened a trojan or were infected with malware.  Linux isn't impervious to these sorts of things but it's not as easily attacked.  Make sure you stay up to date and only install software from trusted repositories.